# GSResponseError: GSResponseError: 403 Forbidden while writing to Bucket

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to write a file from a Compute Engine Instance to a bucket(both belong to the same project).

I followed the steps mentioned here [Python Example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gspythonlibrary) using a service account.

But it is giving the following error:

```
GSResponseError: GSResponseError: 403 Forbidden
[Fri Apr 01 07:12:11 2016] [error] <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access denied.</Message><Details>Provided scope(s) are not authorized</Details></Error>
```

But when I try to write to the bucket from my local machine using the same credentials , code and bucket it writes the file.

I have tried granting every possible permission to the service account, adding account to the bucket.

Comment: Did you set the storage scope to devstorage.full_control when you created the VM?

Comment: @jterrace I don't remember doing that, can this be done later?

Comment: You can't change the scope at runtime. It can only be set at VM creation.

Comment: @jterrace Worked, had to create a new vm , granting all permissions.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. I added an answer so future users can see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common cause for this is that the GCE instance was created without the necessary cloud storage scope.

You can read about scopes here:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/authentication#settingupinstances

Specifically, in this case, the instance was created with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only`, which does not allow bucket creation.

You can see the full list of available scopes here:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#oauth-scopes

Answer (score 0):

In addition to accepted answer (edit queue is full and I can't edit).

Scopes override IAM roles/permissions:

> [Access scopes let you restrict which services the VM can access. The restrictions are applied in addition to Identity and Access Management (IAM) policies.](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-for-securing-service-accounts#access-scopes)

So you need to make sure that the VM does not have a scope that is restrictive such as a read-only scope for Google Storage when you want to write to a bucket. Having IAM write permission to the bucket is not enough if scope explicitly disables write.